# Query with many-to-many relationship by linQ and filter result/ Get dynamic data by LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have many-to-many rel between `Products` and `Category`. I use ef6 to mapping them

when I query to filter by request.categoryId I get these problems:

- with `var query = from product in _context.Products select product ;`
  -> I cannot get category of each product (product.categories==null)
- With `var query = from product in _context.Products select new {product, product.Categories };`
  ->I cannot filter by categoryId, I want to use something like:

`query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.ForEach(category=>category.Id == request.categoryId) );}`
or
`query = query.Where(p => p.Categories.Find(category=>category.Id==request.categoryId) )`
-> The result : `Anonymous type :'a{product,product.Categories}`

how to `product.Categories` auto assign to `List<Category> Categories` in `Product` entity

I don't know how to describe my problem, help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Use first query, but just add `Include`

```cs
var query = 
   from product in _context.Products.Include(x => x.Categories)
   select product;
```

Since it is too verbose to use Query Comperhention in such case, you can try Method Chain syntax.

```cs
var query = _context.Products
   .Include(x => x.Categories)
   .AsQueryable(); // just for changing type to IQueryable
```